# Data overriden by the old message in kafka

Tags: playframework, apache-kafka, akka

Currently, I'm working with apache kafka, and I'm still learning. 
However, we are facing an issue in production.

Scenario: we have two topics in kafka.

First **Opportunity msg** produced and after **Revenue line item msg** produced.

1. Opportunity ( opportunity data + Revenue line item data as an array in the same paylpad)
2. Revenu line item ( seperate payload)

When we receive **opportunity** payload, we are going to db and find the **revenue line items** associated to opportunity and sending it to end user. However our akka actors processing revenue line items faster than oportunity. So when we send revenue line items, they get to the end user before opportunity goes. When we see the data in end user application revenue line item data becomes overriden with old opportunity payload.

Pls suggest if kafka have any approach to solve.

Comment: The message queue like kafka is not design for process something like workflow. Especially, when you put two depend msg in two different topic.

Comment: kafka support ordering of message only at partition level not at topic level, as mentioned above kafka is not a workflow design system , you have to redesign your system according to the workflow you need

Comment: Could you explain it more more precisely?
Are the revenue information (in end user storage) updated according messages from two topics (`opportunity` and `revenue`)?
Why `opportunity` has old information regarding `revenue`?